# "Add" number to the string inside pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following series(type is string)

```
0      F0/Images/1/15.tiff
1      F0/Images/1/15.tiff
2      F0/Images/1/15.tiff
3      F0/Images/1/15.tiff
4      F0/Images/1/15.tiff
```

I want to "add" +1 to the number just before '.tiff'. So I should get a result:

```
0      F0/Images/1/16.tiff
1      F0/Images/1/16.tiff
2      F0/Images/1/16.tiff
3      F0/Images/1/16.tiff
4      F0/Images/1/16.tiff
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: Can you provide us with a snippet of the code you're working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a `regex`.

We can define a function to perform these and then apply it to our column.

```
df
   idx             filename
0    0  F0/Images/1/15.tiff
1    1  F0/Images/1/15.tiff
2    2  F0/Images/1/15.tiff
3    3  F0/Images/1/15.tiff
4    4  F0/Images/1/15.tiff


def add_one(filename):
    number = int(re.search(r'(?<=\/)[0-9]{2}(?=\.tiff)', filename).group()) + 1
    return re.sub(r'(?<=\/)[0-9]{2}(?=\.tiff)', str(number), filename)

df['filename'] = df['filename'].apply(add_one)

df
   idx             filename
0    0  F0/Images/1/16.tiff
1    1  F0/Images/1/16.tiff
2    2  F0/Images/1/16.tiff
3    3  F0/Images/1/16.tiff
4    4  F0/Images/1/16.tiff
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you will always have a path ended with numbers followed by an extension without numbers:

```
yourserie.str.replace('(.*)([0-9]+)(\.[A-Za-z]*)',lambda x:x.group(1)+str(int(x.group(2))+1)+x.group(3))
```

Full example, including input generation:

```
yourserie = pd.Series(['F0/Images/1/15.tiff','F0/Images/1/15.tiff','F0/Images/1/15.tiff'])
yourserie.str.replace('(.*)([0-9]+)(\.[A-Za-z]*)',lambda x:x.group(1)+str(int(x.group(2))+1)+x.group(3))
```

Comment: Could you include an example of this working? When I run this against the column it returns the same value, with no increase on the number.

Comment: i have added my replicated input from yours, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

With a column name of `0`, you can use `str.extract` to do some pandas vectorized regex. *This is dynamic to filenames with any file extension (i.e. not just `.tiff` files)*:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'F0/Images/1/15.tiff',
  1: 'F0/Images/1/15.tiff',
  2: 'F0/Images/1/15.tiff',
  3: 'F0/Images/1/15.tiff',
  4: 'F0/Images/1/15.tiff'}})
s = (df[0].str.extract('(\d+)\..*$').astype(int) + 1).astype(str)
df[0] = df[0].str.extract('(.*/)\d+.*$') + s + df[0].str.extract('(\..*$)')
df
                      0
0   F0/Images/1/16.tiff
1   F0/Images/1/16.tiff
2   F0/Images/1/16.tiff
3   F0/Images/1/16.tiff
4   F0/Images/1/16.tiff
```